# Are there ways of reheating non-kosher food in a kosher oven

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Are there ways of reheating non-kosher food in a kosher oven without rendering the oven non-kosher?

Comment: Double wrap the food? That works vice-versa, with reheating kosher food in a treif oven. I don't know though, and these questions really ought to be posed to a competent rabbi.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a psak-specific matter, @ezra, but a genral halachic concept.

Comment: @ezra I would assume that it works vice versa. I saw some M.Y. question that explains why the double-wrapping works the way that it does. I don't have time to hunt for which Q it is. But, I'd imagine that what works for kosher food in the traif oven works the other way around.

Comment: @DanF I mean it makes sense to me that it would work the other way around, but sometimes the hava amina is wrong.

Comment: @ezra Double-wrapping should be fine. If the non-kosher food(liquid included) doesn't touch the walls of the oven or the plate/grill that holds it up while it's being reheated, it won't render the oven forbidden. If it does, it needs libbun; accomplished by cleaning the oven thoroughly with a degreaser and leaving on highest temp for 30 minutes to an hour.